# TikZ datavisualization error, "Missing number" after closing data bracket

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

*Hello, after a quick search I didn't find this exact question asked before, but if I overlooked something, please let me know.*

I am unable to execute the following code:

Edit: notice the `logarithmic` part, as that is essential to me. If I remove it, the code works fine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                x axis={logarithmic},
                y axis={logarithmic},
                visualize as smooth line]
    data [format=function] {
        var x : interval [0.01:5]; % EDITED: previously -5 but not main problem
        func y = \value x*\value x;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   n
l.15    };
        
?
```

Despite my efforts to find the mistake, I couldn't. I basically copied this code with only a few adjustments and yet it doesn't work. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You cannot use a logarithmic axis if the range contains non-positive values. log(x) is undefined when x <= 0.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the fact that (real-valued) logarithm function is not defined at x <= 0. To control the axis length and the step between ticks, you can try axis options like `length=5cm, ticks={about=5}`.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes,
                x axis={length=6cm, ticks={about=2.5}},
                y axis={length=5cm, ticks={about=5}},
                visualize as line]
    data [format=function] {
        var x : interval [-5:5];
        func y = \value x*\value x;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what solved my problem, as even when using only numbers greater than 0 the error still occurred. I did manage to find the issue though:  apparently, `logarithmic` axes don't work with `school book axes`.  When I tried `scientific axes`, everything worked.

Comment: @APotato Yes, I've found the same as you. Hence you may change the example in question to avoid `interval [-5:5]` and emphasis the real problem between `logarithmic` and `school book axes`. Also, how about having a look at `pgfplots` package?

Comment: I have not yet taken a look at `pgfplots`, and thus far only used it when importing drawings I did in geogebra (which includes it automatically). In what ways is it superior? I am only a novice at both LaTeX and TikZ though, so if it's too complicated I will take a look at a later time.

Comment: @APotato `pgfplots` is as complicated as `tikz`'s `\datavisualization`, but I think the former is more professional and has more users.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was with the `school book axes` and a value of x below zero. Everything works now with the axis-type set as `scientific`.

The following code works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions} % .formats.functions

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [scientific axes,
                    x axis={logarithmic},
                    y axis={logarithmic},
                    visualize as line]
        data [format=function] {
            var x : interval [0.01:100];
            func y = \value x * \value x;
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```